# Which `pandas` testing library to use

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

I can see from the source code that `pandas.testing` just imports a few functions from `pandas.util.testing`.

```
from pandas.util.testing import (
    assert_frame_equal, assert_index_equal, assert_series_equal)
```

I've seen on various blog posts and SO answers that some people use the former and some the latter. Is there an ostensible difference or a best practice?

Comment: This might be helpful, let me know what you think: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/wiki/Testing

Comment: thanks for this link! place it as an answer so i can upvote it

Comment: Sure I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little research, but can verify I have not tried the testing library yet. But this reference, the github repository for this particular pandas sub-library should have some best practices.

- http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/wiki/Testing

One example that helped me understand: https://realpython.com/python-pandas-tricks/#2-make-toy-data-structures-with-pandas-testing-module

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pandas.util.testing` module was deprecated in 1.0, and they recommend to use the public API in `pandas.testing`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#deprecations